# Which JPA @Column elements have a runtime effect?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How are the various `@Column` elements such as `nullable` and `length` used by the persistence provider runtime (i.e. Hibernate) when the application is running?

I understand that some elements are intended for schema generation only, but I cannot find where this is stated.  A careful reading of the JPA 2.1 spec does not seem to shed any light on whether an attribute has a runtime effect or not.

Section 11.1.9 lists all of the `@Column` elements: `name`, `unique`, `nullable`, `insertable`, `updatable`, `columnDefinition`, `table`, `length`, `precision`, `scale`

Section 11.2.2.1 lists the `@Column` elements that are used in schema generation but it does **not** state that the listed elements are **exclusively** used for schema generation. In fact I believe `name` and `table` which are listed also have a runtime effect: they direct the persistence provider's runtime mapping. The only elements not listed are `insertable` and `updatable`, so it seems implied that these have a runtime effect otherwise they have no purpose.

---

From what I have been able to glean from the JPA spec and other SO questions and answers is the following:

@Column elements with **only** a runtime effect:

- `insertable`
- `updatable`

@Column elements with **both** a runtime effect and used for schema generation:

- `table`
- `name`

@Column elements used **only** for schema generation (no effect at runtime):

- `length`
- `nullable`
- `precision`
- `scale`
- `unique`
- `columnDefinition`

---

Is this correct and is their any official or semi-official documentation of this?

Comment: `columnDefinition` is only for schema generation and it overrides `length`, `precision` and `scale`.

Comment: It seems like `columnDefinition` should also override unique and nullable, no? Where did you find this information? Thanks!